# animate() not working for opacity in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm trying to animate a div from 100% opacity to 40% opacity WITHOUT
using fadeTo(). I need to use animate().

It works fine in chrome/FF/safari, but in IE, the opacity doesn't
animate, it simply changes to that after the animation is done.
Happens in IE 7 and 8. I'm doing this:

```
                .animate({
                    width: new_width,
                    top: new_top,
                    left: new_left,
                    padding: new_padding,
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    filter: "alpha(opacity=40)"
                },
```

... it's just not animating the opacity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you just remove `filter: "alpha(opacity=40)"` it will work, the `opacity: 0.4` is all you need...jQuery takes care of the cross-browser differences here.  So your animate call would just be:

```
.animate({
  width: new_width,
  top: new_top,
  left: new_left,
  padding: new_padding,
  opacity: 0.4
})
```